# Obtain support vectors with custom kernel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit learn, with the classifier SVM SVC with a custom kernel, as in the  example:

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel = my_ker, C=0.01)
```

where my_ker is (for illustration purpose only, I do not imply this is a valid or not valid kernel):

```
z = (1 + np.dot(x, np.transpose(y)) )**2
```

I did not find how to obtain the support vectors: a call to

```
print(clf.support_vectors_)
```

returns

```
[]
```

How can I obtain the support vectors ?

Comment: Have you fitted the data yet? Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @VivekKumar Yes, the classifier is fitted to the data. It seems that with the custom kernel, support_vectors_ returns an empty array. With a (non custom) polynomial kernel of degree 2 ( for example: clf = svm.SVC(kernel = 'poly', degree = 2, C = 0.01)  ) the support vectors are returned.

Comment: `clf.support_` works fine, so it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

a function call `clf.fit(X, y)` before `clf.support_vectors_` . Support vectors are learned using the `fit` method.

Comment: This does not answer the question.